# disable function inside bootstrap javascript

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to disable function inside bootstrap after click.

```
<a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right" id="btn04" onclick="myfun();"></span></a>
```

And then would like to enable this bootstrap button in some situation.
please show me the way.
thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?  And what do you mean by "disable"?  Sounds like you could just set a boolean flag in the Javascript, and then check that flag in the function, right?  Bootstram shouldn't have anything to do with it ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var enable = true;
document.getElementById("btn04").disabled = false;

function myfun(){
  if (enable == true) { // condition for disable the button
     enable = false;
     document.getElementById("btn04").disabled = true;
     return false;
  } else {
     enable = true; // condition for enable the button
     document.getElementById("btn04").disabled = false;
     //do some activity.... 
     alert("enable");
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right" id="btn04" onclick="myfun();">Disable</span></a>
```

**You need to handle some based on that you can call function else you can return false;**